# dropzone js why i can't upload my file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropzone.js

Since 2 hours i can't find why i can't upload with dropzone JS my files..

There is my form:

```
<form action="/Volumes/site/vue/upload.php"
    class="dropzone"
    id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

There is my php:

```
<?php
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be   used        instead
 // of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '../upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}
 echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
 print_r($_FILES);
 print "</pre>";
?>
```

First problem: when i drop, i havn't got javascript effects (like the loading and the green button).

Seconde problem, and the most important, my file don't go on my upload folder.. No error, nothing, did i miss something?

EDIT: all my include are checked, i try with this example http://code.runnable.com/UbDApm3qYSEiAADm/drag-and-drop-file-upload-php-for-fileupload
 And nothing work... All the day this problem persist :/

Answer (score -1):

Have you included the dropzone JavaScript and the CSS file?

```
<script src="js/dropzone.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dropzone.css">

<form action="/Volumes/site/vue/upload.php"
    class="dropzone"
    id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

The PHP seems to be okay.

Comment: Yes, all is include.

Comment: This is not an answer for question, please consider adding comment to the question.

Comment: I tested it on your runnable.com link and it seemed to do its job?

Comment: please conisder this as a comment.